# How to print the sum of the current and previous element in a list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to iterate through a list of numbers and print the sum of the current element and the previous element using python. For example,

Given `numbers = [5,10,15,20,25,30,30]`, the output should be `5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 60,`. This is the following code that I have tried, it is very close to the answer but the first element is wrong.

```py
numbers = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 30]

i = 0
for x in range(1, 8):
    print(numbers[i] + numbers[i - 1], end=", ")
    i += 1
```

I am getting the output `35, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 60,`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why use `x`, instead of `i`?

Comment: The biggest problem here is that you're mixing up the _pattern_ of a `for loop` with _pattern_ of a `while loop`. In the battle between these two loops, I'm for `for` :) . And @Felipe's answer perfectly captures how you can do this with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting at index `0`, where it seems your intended output starts at index `1`:

Here is a better solution:

```py
numbers = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 30]

for i in range(len(numbers)):
    if i == 0:
        print(numbers[i])
    else:
        print(numbers[i - 1] + numbers[i])
```

Outputs:

```
5
15
25
35
45
55
60
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution for teaching a beginner (from looking at the OP's code, one can safely assume they are a beginner). And this solution is perfect because it guides the OP with their own original thought pattern. After understanding this, they can move on to '_advanced_' solutions like @blhsing's

Answer (score 7):

You can pair adjacent items of `numbers` by zipping it with itself but padding one with a `0`, so that you can iterate through the pairs to output the sums in a list comprehension:

```
[a + b for a, b in zip([0] + numbers, numbers)]
```

or by mapping the pairs to the `sum` function:

```
list(map(sum, zip([0] + numbers, numbers)))
```

Both would return:

```
[5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 60]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```py
numbers = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 30]

output = [numbers[i]+numbers[i-1] if i > 0 else numbers[i] for i in range(len(numbers))]
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are starting at `i = 0`, so the first number you are adding is the `0` and the `-1` (the last one, in this case). That's why you are getting the `35` (`5+30`).

Answer (score 0):

This list comprehension works:

```py
numbers = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 30]

output = [value + numbers[i-1] if i else value for i, value in enumerate(numbers)]
print(output)

>>> [5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 60]
```

Answer (score 0):

Cheat, and add a `[0]` at the start to prevent the first sum to be wrong.
You'll run into problems at the end, though, because then the list in the `enumerate` is one item longer than the original, so also clip off its last number:

```
print ([a+numbers[index] for index,a in enumerate([0]+numbers[:-1])])
```

Result:

```
[5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 60]
```

If you want to see how it works, print the original numbers before addition:

```
>>> print ([(a,numbers[index]) for index,a in enumerate([0]+numbers[:-1])])
[(0, 5), (5, 10), (10, 15), (15, 20), (20, 25), (25, 30), (30, 30)]
```

The `enumerate` loops over the *changed* list `[0, 5, 15, .. 55]`, where everything is shifted up a place, but `numbers[index]` still returns the correct index from the *original* list. Adding them up yields the correct result.